# AWS forward request between private instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, x-forwarded-for

I have a public subnet holding AWS ELB which forward its requests to a private EC2 instance.

Is there a way I can forward the request from my private EC2 request to another private EC2 instance?

In public instance i used .htaccess with RewriteRules, and I would be happy to use it now, but I don't know how to forward requests privately.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Apache (your reference to RewriteRules implies as much), then you want to investigate mod_proxy, specifically ProxyPass.